# Visual Studio Code: How do I display the file directory in the tab for all files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I have two files with the same name VS Code will display the file directory next to the file name like this
[image]

How do I configure VS Code to display it for all the files? even if there aren't other files with the same name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Settings.json:

> // Controls the format of the label for an editor.
>
> //  - default:
> Show the name of the file. When tabs are enabled and two files have
> the same name in one group the distinguishing sections of each file's
> path are added. When tabs are disabled, the path relative to the
> workspace folder is shown if the editor is active.
>
> //  - short: Show
> the name of the file followed by its directory name.
> //  - medium:
> Show the name of the file followed by its path relative to the
> workspace folder.
> //  - long: Show the name of the file followed by
> its absolute path.

```
  "workbench.editor.labelFormat": "short",
```

Change the `default` setting to `short`.

Comment: I have multiple projects under my workspace. is it possible to display only the project name instead of the directory?

Comment: Those are the only options listed in my answer.  Run through them and see if any work for you - otherwise you are out of luck.